# CLLocationManagerで位置取得のバッググランドタスクがいつからか止まる

Tags: swift, xcode

SwiftでCLLocationManagerで位置取得を行いサーバに送るプログラムを書いています。
動作自体は問題はないのですが、バックグランドに移行ししばらくは位置取得＆サーバ情報送信はしばらくは動いているのですが何かのタイミングでサーバ情報送信が行われなくなります。
時間制限など何か原因はあるのでしょうか？もし対処などご存知の方はご教示いただけると幸いです。

該当ソースを添付します。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    longitude = CLLocationDegrees()
    latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
    keido.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
    ido.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)

    lm = CLLocationManager()
    lm.delegate = self
    lm.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    lm.distanceFilter = 5
    lm.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!){
        longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude
        latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude
        keido.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude)
        ido.text = String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)
    var myUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: NSString(format:"http://(マスクします)/locationget.php?id=xxxxx&longitude=%@&latitude=%@",String(stringInterpolationSegment: longitude),String(stringInterpolationSegment: latitude)) as String)!
    var myRequest:NSURLRequest  = NSURLRequest(URL: myUrl)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(myRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: self.getHttp)
        NSLog("アップデート")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically`と言うpropertyがあって、これがdefaultでtrueです。これがtrueの場合は位置情報が変わる可能性が低いと判断された（例えばご飯を食べてるので暫く同じ場所に滞在している）場合に更新が止まる様です。

[CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically)

Comment: `lm = CLLocationManager()
lm.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
　　（・・・以下省略・・・）`

のようにしたのですが、夜間に止まってしましました。設定方法が違うのでしょうか？？何か気がつく所があればお願いします。

Comment: 先ず一点。`requestAlwaysAuthorization`を呼んでbackgroundでも位置情報を受け取れるか確認しましょう。もう一点は確証はないですが、location managerのdelegateはsingletonにして`application:didFinishLaunching`でinstance化した方が良いかなと思います。何故ならばviewcontrollerだとinstanceが存在してるとは限らないので。

Comment: requestAlwaysAuthorizationを呼んでbackgroundでも位置情報は受け取れています。singletonにしての部分は具体的にどのようにプログラムするのかわからないので、調べて試そうと思います。

Comment: location managerのdelegateは、AppDelegateに設置すればいいかと思いますが、singletonにする必然性を教えていただけないでしょうか？